# How to keep value from re-calculating when you go back in browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a multi-page form for making reservations which calculates the number of transportation services required based on a few factors. You first choose a number of passengers ('#input_2_6') and Depending on the type of vehicle you choose is how many vehicles you will need, so when you choose a vehicle the "Quantity" field ("#input_2_20") is updated. The on the next page/step, you have to choose if you want a one-way or round trip, so when you choose round trip, the Quantity field is multiplied by two. Then on the next page/step, you are just shown the summary of your order (confirmation page).

The problem is, with the current code, if you are on the confirmation page and decide to go back to the previous page to change something (perhaps you decided you don't want the round trip and only need one-way), the quantity number keeps the new value and now it is multiplied by 2 again when choosing round trip.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var totalBook;
    $('#input_2_12').change(function () {
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case 'Escalade|49':
                $('#input_2_20').val(1);
                    totalBook = Math.ceil($('#input_2_6').val() / 5);
                $("#input_2_20").val(totalBook);
                break;
            case 'Suburban|0':
                $('#input_2_20').val(1);
                    totalBook = Math.ceil($('#input_2_6').val() / 6);
                $("#input_2_20").val(totalBook);
                break;
            case 'Van|14':
                $('#input_2_20').val(1);
                    totalBook = Math.ceil($('#input_2_6').val() / 10);
                $("#input_2_20").val(totalBook);
                break;
        }
    });
    totalBookNew = $("#input_2_20").val();
    $('input:radio[name="input_7"]').change(function () {
$('#input_2_20').val(totalBookNew);
        if ($(this).val() == 'Round trip'){
            $('#input_2_20').val(totalBookNew);
            newTotal = totalBookNew * 2;
            $('#input_2_20').val(newTotal);
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'One way'){
            $('#input_2_20').val(totalBookNew);
        } 
    });
});
```

I've tried using the value of 'totalBook' from the first function on the second function but it returns undefined, that's why I created totalBookNew...

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the main issue is after you do the calculations you set the calculated value into the original input field. Your best bet would be to store the calculations elsewhere in hidden html inputs. So you would have an input called something like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="input_2_20_calculated" value=0>
```

Then instead of setting the calculated value back into the input set it in the hidden input instead. Hidden inputs will get passed along with the form, so you would be able to use the calculated values. This is why you get the duplication is because every time the calculation is triggered it's doubling the previous calculated value.

```
totalBookNew = $("#input_2_20").val();
$('input:radio[name="input_7"]').change(function () {
$('#input_2_20').val(totalBookNew); //This line can be deleted
    if ($(this).val() == 'Round trip'){
        $('#input_2_20').val(totalBookNew); //You can also delete this line
        newTotal = totalBookNew * 2;
        $('#input_2_20_calculated').val(newTotal);
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'One way'){
        $('#input_2_20_calculated').val(totalBookNew);
    } 
});
```

As a cautionary side note you should recalculate on the backend. Don't calculate in the front end and trust those calculations on the back end. It's easy to manipulate the form data on submit and post fake numbers.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. The extra hidden input field was an eye-opener! About your side note...  Do I have to do the same calculations over again? or just a few validations? I am using Wordpress with gravity forms and I'm not that great with PHP (or with js as you may have noticed)